# Does Morris traversal visit some nodes more than once?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, inorder

I'm solving [LeetCode problem of inorder tree traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/) and implemented Morris traversal as suggested on the solutions page. Here it is:

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode() {}
    public TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    public TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public static List<Integer> inorderTraversalMorris(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeNode current = root;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.left != null){
            TreeNode next = current.left;
            TreeNode appendTo = next;
            while(appendTo.right != null){
                appendTo = appendTo.right;
            }
            current.left = null;
            appendTo.right = current;
            current = next;
        } else {
            result.add(current.val);
            current = current.right;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem I see is that while re-balancing the tree to be a Threaded binary tree the algorithm visits some nodes twice. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Do you mean you have cases where the same value is added to the array list multiple times? Can you give an example tree for which that happens?

Comment: Two weeks passed ... no reaction?